# How to rename files with incrementing numbers to files with that number plus 10

Tags: bash

Hi I have a list of files ex. 0.png, 1.png ... 60.png, 61.png and I want to rename all the files to 10.png,11.png ... 70.png, 71.png however I do not know how I could do that.

Comment: Your operating system will offer an option for renaming a file named `X` to a new file named `Y`. You can do that for every file that you want to rename and you're done.
If you're looking for an _automated_ solution, then it will be useful to point out the operating system (Windows, Linux etc) and the desired implementation language (bash, Java, Python,...).

Comment: Note that you need to either process the files in reverse order or change some other part of the name, otherwise file01 will collide with the existing file11, will collide with the existing file21 etc.

Answer (score 1):

In bash, you can use a parameter expansion to handle the rename, e.g.

```
for name in *.png; do
    val="${name%.png}"
    val=$((val+10))
    mv "$name" "$val.png"
done
```

**Explanation**

- `val` is created from the parameter expansion `"${name%.png}"` which simply trims `".png"` from the right-hand side of the filename.
- `val=$((val+10))` adds `10` to the number.
- `mv "$name" "$val.png"` moves the file from its original name to the new name with the value increased by `10`.

If you want to eliminate the intermediate `val` variable, you can do it all in a single expression, e.g.

```
for name in *.png; do
    mv "$name" "$((${name%.png} + 10)).png"
done
```

Look things over and let me know if you have further questions.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the filenames are of the form number.ext, this function would do the trick.

```
#!/bin/bash

function rename_file() {
    local file=$1
    local fname=$(($(echo $file | cut -d. -f1) + 10))
    local ext=$(echo $file | cut -d. -f2)
    mv $file $fname.$ext
}
```

To rename a file, call rename_file file_name in your shell script.